# Issue relating to deactivation of css theme capability in Codename One Preferences

Tags: codenameone

I have activated and then deactivated css theme capability. Post the fact, the css file was still there and when the project is run, it still tries to load from the css file. Should not have been removed?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the file is explicitly deleted on the toggle off. Deleting user code (e.g. CSS) is sometimes scary so we leave it to you. Make sure the operation succeeded before deleting the file and keep a backup.

Comment: The problem is that if it is not deleted, it keeps trying to load it and the `theme` added using the theme editor is being deleted. Before deleting a file, IntelliJ prompts for a check to see where is it linked to. So I get a good idea of what is going on.
I did delete it, and added again a basic `theme` through the editor. Seems to work fine thus far.
Curious to see what is the case if I reactivate it. Will leave that for an experimental application though.